# Calculate Auto sizing of Grid Rows/Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a project that allows you to preview the XAML you are editing. As a part of it, I would like to be able to click on my preview and jump to relevant parts of my XAML.

I am currently doing this by calculating from all the `RowDefinitions` / `ColumnDefinitions` what size `"*"` is, than using those sizes to figure out where the click occured in the `Grid`. I run into problens when I reach an `"Auto"` size.

I know you can use `XamlReader.Parse()` to create an object tree from the XAML, parse that into its top level object, and if that object is a `FrameworkElement` or a `UIElement` you can use the `ActualWidth` / `ActualHeight` or `Measure()` to figure out how big an object (w/ size `"Auto"`) actually is.

My trouble is coming from the fact that I am only really dealing with `XmlElement` and `XmlNode` (s) to parse through my XAML. I can't really cast one of these to an `FrameworkElement` using `.Parse()` because they are not top-level elements, and some of them require resources defined on the top-level element.

Any thoughts/ideas on how I can get the `ActualWdith` / `ActualHeight` or compute what `"Auto"` is in the C# codebehind?

EDIT:
A specific scenario from the XAML I'm working with, simplified some.

```
<root>
    <!-- resources here -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="252" />
            <RowDefinition Height="77" />
            <RowDefinition Height="168" />
            <RowDefinition Height="170" />
            <RowDefinition Height="85" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
        <Grid Grid.Row="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- How big is this? -->
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentControl Content="{ns:Foo Name=A}" />
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{ns:Foo Name=B}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get much help if you don't post some relevant code and an example of the XAML you're trying to parse or something.

Comment: @HighCore the point is that this needs to be able to work for "any" XAML. But I posted a specific example anyway